# Get Element with jQuery .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, yahoo

If I'm using jQuery's `.on()` function like this (there's more to it but this is the main problem area extracted):

```
$(document).on("click", 
          $("#contcont a, #leftnav li a, #leftnav li ul a, #mainarea-home a").not(".secitem-mid a"),
    function clicker(event, sData) {

    var $this = $(this);

    sHREF = $this.attr("href");

    alert(sHREF);

} );
```

I'm getting undefined so what would be the best way to actually get the element that's being clicked?  I need `.on()` so that it always occurs, obviously, instead of having to attach it to all the elements every time new data is loaded (this is through Yahoo! stores so it's a necessity to do it this way).  Thanks.

Comment: use the `event` obj that you passed in the `on()`

Comment: Post html code. Also do you have href attribute in the a tag u clicked?

Comment: @freakish The code isn't fine. The selector argument is invalid, so it's being ignored. That results in a click event handler that's bound directly to the document - hence the undefined `href`  attribute - rather than delegated to anchors. At no point has "the code runs" been synonymous with "the code is correct".

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yep, you're right. My apologies, I was too fast in my judgement.

Comment: The reason I was trying to use that not selector for the second argument is because it's kind of a tricky setup.  I'm aware that the second argument should be a string but it's actually firing when I click so now I'm trying to just get the clicked element.  I'll log the event to the console and get the element or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second argument to [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) is a ***selector***, not a jQuery object; it's used for event delegation.

If you meant to hook those up directly, then:

```
$("#contcont a, #leftnav li a, #leftnav li ul a, #mainarea-home a").not(".secitem-mid a").on("click", function clicker(event, sData) {

    var $this = $(this);

    sHREF = $this.attr("href");

    alert(sHREF);

});
```

If you really wanted to use event delegation, the `.not` part makes it a bit tricky because (depending on your markup) you might have to repeat it on each of the selectors in your main series. Since that's ugly, you might be better off handling that particular case afterward in the handler function:

```
$(document).on("click", "#contcont a, #leftnav li a, #leftnav li ul a, #mainarea-home a", function clicker(event, sData) {

    var $this = $(this);

    // Handle the "not" part
    if (!$this.is(".secitem-mid a")) {
        sHREF = $this.attr("href");

        alert(sHREF);
    }
});
```

Separately, though: It's usually best to root your delegation in the container nearest the elements you want to handle. If your `#contcont`, `#leftnav`, and `#mainarea-home` elements *aren't* dynamic, I'd probably look at rooting the delegation in them rather than `document`, e.g.:

```
$("#contcont"     ).on("click", "a:not(.secitem-mid a)", clicker);
$("#leftnav"      ).on("click", "li a:not(.secitem-mid a)", clicker);
$("#mainarea-home").on("click", "a:not(.secitem-mid a)", clicker);
function clicker(event, sData) { ... }
```

Note I only needed three, not four; your `#leftnav li ul a` selector is already covered by `#leftnav li a`.

---

And just a bit off-topic: Beware that you're using a *named function expression*, which can be [tricky on IE8 and earlier](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html). My final example above does away with that, making it a function *declaration* instead.

Comment: If the OP could clarify how `.secitem-mid a` falls into the structure, maybe you could do something like `#leftnav li:not(.secitem-mid) a`. It could get rid of your `if` statement, but it would make the selector even uglier.

Comment: @lbstr: Yeah, exactly, as I say where and whether it has to be repeated depends on the markup.

Comment: The second part (testing the element with a conditional) is exactly what I ended up doing except I tested the parent's class but I think the way you wrote it is actually more efficient.  Thanks!

Comment: I figured a way around all of this.  The `secitem-mid` links were just causing issues and not loading properly but now I'm filtering the data returned by `$.get()` which loads the link's document's HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The ON method can also be used without delegation. If no content is added after the page has loaded the following code can be used to select the elements:

```
var elements = $('#contcont a, #leftnav li a, #leftnav li ul a, #mainarea-home a').not('.secitem-mid a');
```

And the following to do a bit of event handling:

```
$(elements).on('click', function() {
    //do something
});
```